# Debian interfaces file - ignore gateway and dns entries from dhcp

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp

In gentoo, this is as simple as:

```
dhcp_ethX="nodns nogateway"
```

How should I go about this in the interfaces file?

Comment: What do you want, set them statically or use the current values?

Comment: I want to configure interface via DHCP, but ignore the given dns and gateway settings, this is for multiple uplink configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

edit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

check the line:

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

and uncomment it and set whatever dns servers you want to use

then in the request section below there will be something like this:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu;
```

remove domain-name-servers and routers, that should remove the dns server and router/gateway requests via dhcp

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `supersede` instead of `prepend`? Because if the DHCP server would reply with DNS servers despite you don't request them, they would still be used (just prepended).

Answer (score 5):

While not doing exactly what you've asked for, the [ifmetric](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifmetric/) package may provide a better solution.

```
sudo aptitude install ifmetric
```

Then in your **/etc/network/interfaces** file assign metrics to your interfaces.  Note that *not* having a metric is the same as having a *zero* metric.

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    metric 1

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

The above makes it so that when *eth1* is plugged in, its routes will take precedence over routes from *eth0*.  This may be better because you allow the routes to failover, so that it will still have a default route even if the *eth1* interface is unplugged.

This doesn't affect dns settings, so depending on exactly what you want you may still have to uncomment and amend the line in **/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf**:

```
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

and remove **domain-name-servers** from the **request** list that immediately follows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an exactly analagous command for /etc/network/interfaces; you'll have to set things up the way you like via the post-up command, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the DHCP server then set the settings you want for this specific host based on the MAC address, otherwise setting a post-up script in /etc/network/interfaces is probably the simplest option